# Failure to find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have been trying to set up a spring boot project but am getting an error. I researched and tried various options but no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

The pom.xml file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.sysyaas.pardakhtyary</groupId>
<artifactId>auth</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>master</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>Auth Server Pardakhtyary</description>

<!--<properties>-->
    <!--<java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
    <!--<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>-->
<!--</properties>-->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Swagger-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.194</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--microservices-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>AuthServer</finalName>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:${spring-cloud.version} in https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 113, column 25 -> [Help 2]

Answer (score 15):

You need to specify `${spring-cloud.version}`. Add `properties` section into your pom:

```
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Ofc, instead of "Greenvich.RELEASE" you can use any other version of `spring-cloud-dependencies`

Comment: I also had to add missing <dependencyManagement> which helped me fix the error message

Answer (score 3):

Well, you commented out

```
<!--<properties>-->
    <!--<java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
    <!--<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>-->
<!--</properties>-->
```

So Maven has no idea how to get the placeholder for

```
<version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
```

**Un-comment** these lines and you should be good to go.
There is also a new version for that module, `Greenwich.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 2):

Above your `<dependencies>` starting bracket, add the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        ...
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue in Intellij Idea by doing followings steps:

1. Click on the maven tab and type the following command:

   `mvn clean install`
2. After this you will get errors about **SpringFramework**. You can fix it by doing:

- Right click on project
- go to maven in the contextual menu
- And click on **"reload project"**

Answer (score 2):

Dependency requires the version number. Add the version number like below or refer https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp for the latest version of the dependency that can be used.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```